# Rails: Is a single table a good design choice for this problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, sti

I just recently inherited a Rails application and am debating an architectural decision moving forward.  Here's a bit of background...  Feedback appreciated.

There are, currently, 16 different ad types, all with a set of the same attributes, several with one or two additional attributes, and a couple with three or four.

Currently each ad type has a separate model and table with the respective columns, and a separate controller and views in a CMS too used for basic CRUD.  The CMS takes advantage of inherited_resources, so that limits some of the duplication.

I wrote out the attribute set -- there are 20 or so that cover all ad types.  Certain ad types have associations -- several has_many associations where the foreign key is stored on the associated table and a few belongs_to.

The ads have no real behavior.  Specific ad types are simply displayed on various pages, so as long as I can determine if there is an ad of a specific type, we're golden.

I am debating moving to a single model, table, and controller, but want to get as much input as possible from the stackoverflow community on whether or not this is 1) a good fit for the problem 2) any performance concerns 3) any potential programming bottlenecks I haven't though of.  Here is my thinking so far...

---

Assuming a route /:location/:ad_type/new (e.g. /homepage/ad_type_1/new):

The ad_controller would create @ad with ad_type set to params[:location] + params[:ad_type] and render the new view which would contain a series of conditionals for displaying the appropriate partials for the given ad_type.  Submit would fire the create action creating the ad with the expected attributes defined for the ad type, one of which in this case would be ad_type = homepage_ad_type_1.

I've not thought as much about retrieving the data, but assuming the ad_type column is set correctly, I should be able to create an "of_type" scope that pulls records based on the ad_type column.  Not sure if I'm missing something there.

Validations will vary based on the ad_type value.

I'm not entirely certain how many ads will exist at any given time, but I feel this could be addressed at a later time.  Either by moving off some of the stale rows to an ad_archives table or similar.

Your thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: considering the app details in DB design will lead to a DB that may work well FOR ONLY THAT APP. "May" because you're focusing on how the app wants to work and not on how the database will best deliver results. But nearly every time I've seen db's built by developers, they never work well once other systems/people need to get at the same date. It's virtually always extracted to the next db built by developers. and so on until you've got some awesome spaghetti... not within any one system, oh no, developers rock at tight code; but BETWEEN systems is where the spaghetti is strung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use a single table model for this, but if it makes sense to use multiple controllers/views, you don't have to restrict yourself to a single controller, and you can still query ads based on their type without using conditionals. Example:

```
create_table :people do |t|
  t.string first_name
  t.string last_name
  # some other properties...
  t.string type
end

class Student < Person
end

class Teacher < Person
end

Person.all # shows all students and teachers
Teacher.all # shows all teachers
```

So it would be easy to make a Teachers controller and a Students controller, as well as a People controller.

Comment: But is there an advantage to this?  Why would I need/want multiple controllers/views?  I can see having the separate models for easier querying.

Comment: @Eric M.: Your different ad types might have different views. Having different controllers would be the easiest way to achieve this. At the moment you have conditionals which decide whether or not to display certain properties, but what if the different ad types have more and more differences as time goes on? Having different controllers and views creates better support for this scenario and I think it's a cleaner way to do it. They can share a partial for the properties they have in common and add their own fields as necessary.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of trying to minimize code duplication?  I agree that the views w/ if conditionals is the dirty point.

Comment: Also, we could always switch to the multiple models/controllers piece down the road, right?  Right now the column is ad_type, but I'm assuming there is a way to set the STI column for Rails or to simply rename it to "type" if not.

Comment: You could switch gears later, but I think it's easier to support it now. There might be some code duplication in your controllers, but there might be a smart way to inherit from your People controller to minimize these. But, do it however you prefer. And yes, you can add STI in now by adding the "type" column (or maybe changing ad_type to type) and deleting the other tables, as long as it's not in PROD. If you have stuff in PROD right now, some data migration might be necessary.